# why my php script not insert data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

[image]The function of this script is to enter the data into mysql database and print the JSON code for use in the Android application, but when testing it gives this result

Json Result after Testing On PostMan Tool

```
{
    "status": 2,
    "message": "Missing mandatory parameters"
}
```

It connects the data base and receives data from the Android application and sends it to the server and returns the result of true or false and then print the code Json on the result

```
<?php
$random_salt_length = 32;
/**
* Queries the database and checks whether the user already exists
* 
* @param $username
* 
* @return
*/
function userExists($username){
    $query = "SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = ?";
    global $con;
    if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    return false;
}

/**
* Creates a unique Salt for hashing the password
* 
* @return
*/
function getSalt(){
    global $random_salt_length;
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($random_salt_length));
}

/**
* Creates password hash using the Salt and the password
* 
* @param $password
* @param $salt
* 
* @return
*/
function concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt){
    global $random_salt_length;
    if($random_salt_length % 2 == 0){
        $mid = $random_salt_length / 2;
    }
    else{
        $mid = ($random_salt_length - 1) / 2;
    }

    return
    substr($salt,0,$mid - 1).$password.substr($salt,$mid,$random_salt_length - 1);

}
?>
<?php
$response = array();
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include 'db/db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) && isset($input['full_name']) && isset($input['email']) && isset($input[ 'idcountry']) && isset($input[ 'born'])  && isset($input[ 'country'])   && isset($input[ 'city'])   ){
    $username = $input['username'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $fullName = $input['full_name'];
    $email = $input['email'];
    $idcountry= $input['idcountry'];
    $born = $input['born'];
    $country = $input['country'];
    $city = $input['city'];

    //Check if user already exist
    if(!userExists($username)){

        //Get a unique Salt
        $salt         = getSalt();

        //Generate a unique password Hash
        $passwordHash = password_hash(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //Query to register new user
        $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO member(username, full_name, password_hash, salt , email , id_con ,born ,country,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss",$username,$fullName,$passwordHash,$salt,$email , $idcountry , $born , $country , $city);
            $stmt->execute();
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "User created";
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    else{
        $response["status"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User exists";
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `password_hash()` adds a salt to the password automatically. There's no need to add your own.

Comment: You'd have to show us the PostMan request data and headers, we have no idea what you sent, or in what format, but possibly you missed something out

Comment: You'll need to check the output from `print_r($input)` to make sure all the keys are present and spelled the same with the same case.

Comment: you need to pass the data in JSON format in the body of your request. The PHP code is expecting JSON but you are sending querystring parameters instead, so it does not recognise them. You have to match the data format the server is expecting, you can't just use whatever you like

Comment: @ADyson {
    "status": 2,
    "message": "Missing mandatory parameters"
}

Comment: that's the response. I'm talking about what you're sending in the _request_.

Comment: Yes I sent the key and value from the body and still get the same result

Comment: Show exactly what you did please

Answer (score 0):

You transfer the parameters through query parameters but you try to read it from the POSTed body, which is empty.

http://localhost/member/register.php?username=XXX&password=YYY....

versus

`$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: I did not understand yet

Comment: @kvra13: On your screenshot you are on the tab 'Params'. Those values are part of the query sent to the web server. On your screenshot there is also a tab 'body'. Your php code reads out that one.

Comment: So what is the solution

Comment: I use an Android application to send data

Comment: I think the 'Body' of the query is empty. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I think that too. But I am writing the user data in the application and the application code is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195403/discussion-between-kvra13-and-user5329483).